# Then $H/Z(H)$ is isomorphic to ______________?

Tags: group-theory

Given $H= \left\{ \begin{bmatrix} 1 & a& b\\ 0&1&c \\0&0& 1 \end{bmatrix}\middle|\, a, b ,c \in \mathbb{Q}\right\}$ under multiplication

Then $H/Z(H)$ is isomorphic to ______________?

My attempt : I know  that $Z(H)= \left\{ \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0& b\\ 0&1&0 \\0&0& 1 \end{bmatrix}\middle|\,  b \in \mathbb{Q}\right\}$

But here I'm not able to proceed further?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint**

Consider $\varphi :H\to \mathbb Q^2$ defined by $$\varphi \begin{pmatrix}1&a&b\\0&1&c\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}=(a,c).$$

Tasks :

- Check it's a Group homomorphism.
- Is it surjective ?
- What is its kernel ?
- Conclusion ?

Comment: How  u got $(a,c)$ ? im not getting can u leaborate more @surb

Comment: @jasmine: Sorry, I don't understand your question.

Comment: got its  @surb  it okay now  thanks u